# Best way to backup data and settings before reinstalling ubuntu?

Tags: backup, reinstall

I want to switch from Ubuntu 21.04 to 20.04 LTS and was wondering if there is a way to backup my settings (e.g. Gnome extensions) and data (Directions and files) in a way which makes it easy to restore it after switching to the LTS version.
What do you guys recommend?

Comment: "Everything is a file". Backing up your home folder is generally sufficient.  However I don't recommend it.    You must reinstall since you can't downgrade to an earlier release. Because you're going "backwards" almost two years, I would expect there to be some problems if you try to use configs from newer software on older software.  So you can definitely copy from your old home folder, but it would be wise to expect at least a few problems that you'll need to hunt down. If you're not familiar with fixing problems in Linux, it's probably best to set everything back up cleanly after reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That's how I will do it now!

Comment: Save the settings files and READ (and interpret) them to re-create a similar setup / settings after re-installing. I generally do so also to have a "clean" update / install. It isn't as easy as the automation, but creates a stable computer. But I also take notes as I install software, by that allowing me to redo "the same" install and settings changes.

Comment: You seem to imply it's a desktop system, so I'd just *upgrade via re-install* which allows you to install a new system to a newer (or in this case older) release. You just re-use existing partitions and do **not** format which triggers this install. Going backwards can mean some older programs are incapable of reading data files created/modified by later programs -so you'll need to ensure an older version can read each app you're using where you used a new program; but this issue can be a problem even on data restores so isn't specific to a *upgrade via re-install*.